# flutter_local_notification code no longer working

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

My push notification code was working as of yesterday but now I'm getting error for `SelectNotificationCallback`.

I've added a screenshot of the code below.

[image]

Comment: could you add the flutter_local_notification version that you are using?

Comment: what is the full error.. you just posted a red line on SelectNotificationCallback.. please post the stack log

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the package?

Check the changelog for the latest versions:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog

10.0.0:

`onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: invoked only when the app is running. This works for when a user has selected a notification or notification action. This replaces the onSelectNotification callback that existed before.`